# Mongodb SQL - How to put a default where clause like 1=1

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to put a default where clause like below.

```
select * from emp_table where 
(
emp_name in (<emp_list_selected_from_api>) or ('All') in (<emp_list_selected_from_api>)
)
```

Here "All" is default filter, using above query, I can keep displaying all employees, unless any specific is selected using filter.
How to write such query in Mongodb.

Comment: There's a query operator for this: `$or`

Comment: Not the MongoDB way of doing it. Not the smart way with any database really. Instead you dynamically construct the query object. That's why they are "objects" and not a DSL contructed from "words".

Comment: Basically you are looking for code like this. `var query = {}; if (emp_list.length) { query['emp_name'] = { "$in": emp_list }; } db.employee.find(query);`. That's the JavaScript way, but you don't even specify a language you are using. That's why it's different to SQL.